# Optimization Problem multivariable calculus or single variable

Tags: calculus, optimization

Problem is that a right circular cylinder is inscribed in a sphere of radius a .What is height of cylinder when its volume is maximal ?

As per suggested by answer i attempted

[image]

Any hints please ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with a single variable, say $r$.

Imagine the radius of the sphere, $a$ starts at the center of the cylinder and goes to the edge of the rim of the cylinder.  This creates a right triangle with $a$ as the hypotenuse, $r$ as one leg, and $\sqrt{a^2-r^2}$ as the other leg.  Note $r$ is also the radius of the top/base of the cylinder.

Now you can expresss the height of the cylinder as $2\sqrt{a^2-r^2}$ and write out the formula for the cylinder's volume in one variable $r$ (note $a$ is a constant in this case), and find the maximum by taking the first derivative.

(Your answer will still include the variable $a$, which is what you want)

In this figure imagine that where it says $8$ it is $a$.  And where it says $\frac{h}{2}$, that's $\sqrt{a^2-r^2}$ and thus the height of the cylinder as $2\sqrt{a^2-r^2}$

[image]

Comment: Can u pls suggest a figure

Comment: image added to answer

Answer (score 2):

OK so,

$$
V_{cylinder}=\pi*r^2*h
$$

Use pythagore's theorem you will find : (R is the radius of the sphere)

$$
R^2=\frac{h^2}{4}+r^2
$$

So

$$
r=\sqrt{R^2-\frac{h^2}{4}}
$$

So

$$
V(h)_{cylinder}=\pi*\left(R^2-\frac{h^2}{4}\right)*h
$$

By derivation :
$$
V'(h) = \pi*R^2-\frac{3*\pi h^2}{4}
$$
And for $0<h<\frac{2R\sqrt{3}}{2}$ V' is negative and positive if $h>\frac{2R\sqrt{3}}{2}$

So V is max for $h=\frac{2R\sqrt{3}}{2}$

shadock :)

Comment: Sorry I use r and not a but it's the same... :)

Comment: Can you please suggest figure for this

Comment: Look under my comment there is a beautiful picture by @Ivo Terek ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** look at the cross-section. The height is $2a \sin \theta$. Find what $\theta$ maximizes the volume.

[image]

---

You know that the volume of a cylinder with radius $r$ and height $h$ is $V= \pi r^2h$. So $$V(\theta) = 2\pi a^2\cos^2\theta a\sin \theta = 2\pi a^3(1-\sin^2\theta)\sin \theta = 2\pi a^3(\sin \theta - \sin^3\theta).$$
Working with the last expression, we have: $$V'(\theta) = 2\pi a^3(\cos \theta  -3\sin^2\theta\cos \theta) = 2\pi a^3\cos \theta(1-3\sin^2\theta)$$

But $\cos \theta = 0$ is a situation that would give us no volume. So go for $1 - 3 \sin^2\theta = 0$, that is $\sin \theta = \pm \sqrt{3}/3$. Now look at the picture again and see what makes sense.

Comment: There are 3 values of theta coming but which one is to be taken pi\2 , sin (theta) =1\SQRT3

Comment: No, you have to write the volume of the cylinder in function of $\theta$, using that the radius of the cylinder is $a\cos \theta$. Then you'll have your volume function $V = V(\theta)$. The $\theta$ you're looking for is the one such that $V'(\theta) = 0$ and $V''(\theta)< 0$.

Comment: Yes i know after setting derivative to 0 i get three values n second derivative computation is hard .

Comment: Pls see my attempt . I am not getting correct answer

Comment: I'll add a hint.

Comment: Ok i have taken positive value of sin . But when i substitute in V it doesn't give correct answer .my answer came out 4pia^(3)/3sqrt(3)